# Finding an angle of a triangle inscribed in a rectangle

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

In a rectangle ABCD there is a triangle ABP, with its vertex P on the CD side of the rectangle.
The known measures of the sides are:
$$AB = a$$
$$AD = (2\ -\sqrt3)a$$

I need to find the DAP triangle, knowing that it is valid the relation:
$$AP^2+AD^2 = BP^2$$

I'm stuck with this and I'd really appreciate some suggestions or a solution.

Comment: Is there anything else you can add? This seems incomplete.

Comment: I'm sorry I can't, I had this problem on a trigonometry test and I couldn't solve it.
What I wrote is precisely what was written in the test.

Comment: Ah, just noticed that. Yes, it seems solvable, I will try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### [image]

Since $ABCD$ is a rectangle, $AD = BC$.

So, $\ AP^2+AD^2 = BP^2 = BC^2+PC^2 \Rightarrow AP = PC = x$.

By the Pythagorean Theorem for triangle $ADP$, we have that:
$$ AD^2+DP^2 = AP^2 \Rightarrow (2-\sqrt{3})^2a^2+(x-a)^2 = x^2$$
Simplifying this equation gives: $$x = \frac{(2-\sqrt{3})^2+1}{2}a = (4-2\sqrt{3})a = 2(2-\sqrt{3})a$$

So, $AP = x = 2AD$, which means that $ADP$ is a $30-60-90$ triangle and $\angle DAP = 60^{\circ}$